# Adding Screenshots Specifically For 4-inch, 7-inch, and 10-inch Screen

Tags: resolution, pixel, publishing, google-play, screenshot

My boss invited me and assigned me now as publisher for the app in Google Play. I have a 7-inch Google Nexus 7 tablet to take screenshot of any one of my sample projects I've made and post and upload it into the 7-inch screenshot section. Now, I want to take some screenshots and post it this time into the 4-inch screenshot section. However, I got a 4.5-inch smartphone that runs on Android ICS.

I was wondering. Is it valid if I posted on the 4-inch screenshot section using all my snapshots taken from the 4.5-inch screenshot image or there is a specific requirement for that like the width and height in pixels?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The size of the screen does not directly dictate the number of pixels. You should be taking screenshots at *different resolutions*, not different screen sizes. I have a 16 inch screen on my laptop, and a 5 inch screen on my phone, but they both have the same resolution (1920x1080).

Use the most common devices to get some average screen resolutions for the different form factors. Then you can produce all the screenshots on a device that has the highest resolution (as long as you can change the resolution of your game to whatever you wish).

Comment: It's like adjusting the right resolution according to the resolution from the phone's screen. I see.